# Mapping scores to People

Tags: python

Am trying to access a file that contain different people with their scores, so I need to calculate each total score add them and relate it to the respective person who  scored those point. Then I need to sort the score and print in terminal who took what what position with respect to the point he scored. And the person with the least score took first followed by the second least and the person with the highest score took last. This code is not complte am stuck.

````
with open('golf.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
    score = []
    name = []
    for i in file:
        i = i.split(':')
        name = i[0]
        score = i[1]

    list_score = []
    score = score.split(",")
    total_of_scores = 0
    for k in score:
        total_of_scores += k
        list_score.append(total_of_scores)
    print(list_score)
input ```
Bob Jones:4,6,3,3,4,3,5,5,4,4,3,3,2,3,4,3,4,4
Ted Smith:3,3,3,3,4,3,5,5,4,3,3,3,2,3,4,3,4,4
Taylor Martin:4,4,3,3,4,3,5,6,4,4,4,3,2,3,5,3,5,4

outout
FIRST:Ted Smith
SECOND:Adam Lee
THIRD:Mike Davis
LAST:Brian Foste
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**golf.txt**:

```
Bob Jones:4,6,3,3,4,3,5,5,4,4,3,3,2,3,4,3,4,4
Ted Smith:3,3,3,3,4,3,5,5,4,3,3,3,2,3,4,3,4,4
Taylor Martin:4,4,3,3,4,3,5,6,4,4,4,3,2,3,5,3,5,4
```

**Code:**

```
with open('golf.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
    scorecard=[]
    for i in file:
        name,scores=i.split(":")
        #print(name)
        score=0
        for i in scores.split(","):
            score+=int(i)
        scorecard.append([name,score])
    #print(scorecard)
    sorted_scorecard=sorted(scorecard,key=lambda x:x[1]) #sorted by the scores
    for name,score in sorted_scorecard:
        print(name)   #You can print score also to see the score
```

**Output:**

```
Ted Smith
Bob Jones
Taylor Martin
```

Comment: Yeah sure you are right I just provided the first three inputs I got from the question becuse the list is long it contains ten different players.

Comment: let me know if it is working fine or not @MuhammedCham.

Comment: if your query is resolved don't forget to ✔️ the answer :)..! @MuhammedCham